# Validate dates before executing sql in asp.net

Tags: .net, asp.net, validation

I have a data grid bound to a data source in the typical way (simplified for brevity):

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="ds" runat="server" ConnectionString="xxx"
     ProviderName="yyy" SelectCommand="SELECT "a from A where date > ?">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="txtDateFrom" Name="fromDate" PropertyName="Value" Type="DateTime"/>
    </SelectParameters>
```

...

I also have a custom validator on txtDateFrom

```
<asp:CustomValidator ID="fromDateCorrectVal" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtDateFrom"  ErrorMessage="From date is not valid" OnServerValidate="fromDateCorrectVal_ServerValidate" Display="None"/>
```

Where the code behind is similar to this:

```
protected void fromDateCorrectVal_ServerValidate(object source, ServerValidateEventArgs args)
{
    DateTime parsedDate;
    if (!DateTime.TryParse(tryDate, out parsedDate))
    {
            args.IsValid = false;
            fromDateCorrectVal.ErrorMessage = "Invalid from date";
    }

}
```

But this doesn't seem to work! If I enter garbage into the date field, I get an ASP error - parsing invalid date tokens.

How can I stop the SQL attempting to fire, if the validation fails? (I suspect I need to check for the page isValid at some point, but my efforts to try this in the datasource_Selecting event doesn't seem to work)

Thanks in advance for any help

Ryan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can handle this with the [SqlDataSource.Selecting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.sqldatasource.selecting.aspx) event and call Cancel.

> By adding an event handler delegate to
>   handle the  Selecting event, you can
>   perform any additional preprocessing
>   required or cancel the database query
>   entirely. Because the
>   SqlDataSourceSelectingEventArgs class
>   is derived from the 
>   SqlDataSourceCommandEventArgs class,
>   you can cancel a pending 
>   SqlDataSource database query by
>   setting the  Cancel property to true.
>   You can examine and manipulate the 
>   CommandText,  Parameters collection,
>   and other database query properties
>   prior to running the query by
>   accessing the  DbCommand object
>   exposed by the  Command property. You
>   can also examine the 
>   DataSourceSelectArguments object that
>   is passed to the  Select method by
>   accessing the  Arguments property.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.sqldatasourceselectingeventargs.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Another way to accomplish this is to use a CompareValidator:

```
<asp:CompareValidator id="dateValidator" runat="server" Type="Date" Operator="DataTypeCheck" ControlToValidate="txtDateFrom" ErrorMessage="Error!" />
```

This validator has a built-in Date validation operation and will not allow the page to continue processing until all validations pass.